# Implement Deref for an enum to get its discriminant?

Tags: rust, enums

The [`Deref` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#examples) has the following example code as an example of how to use `Deref`, with some immaterial differences:

```rust
struct X(u8);

impl std::ops::Deref for X {
    type Target = u8;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

It implements a simple [smart pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html) by enclosing the underlying value and enabling additional functionality to be implemented.

I want to use this, but my value is range-constrained, i.e. I need the value within bounds tighter than 0-255, so considered using an enum to bound the range and get value via its discriminant. This works, but I can no longer implement the Deref behavior for it:

```rust
enum Y { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H }

impl std::ops::Deref for Y {
    type Target = u8;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &(self as u8) // errors
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement this behavior for enum?

Comment: No, and this is not what `Deref` is meant for at all. How is this better than just implementing a `to_u8` method for `Y`?

Comment: @isaactfa It's not the intent? The documentation has this exact example: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#examples

Comment: Its not clear how your type expresses itself as a "smart pointer", and its not clear what the range of *values* it hold/references has to do with `Deref`. Dereferencing an enum to get its discriminant does not sound intuitive at all. What do you hope to achieve with this?

Comment: @kmdreko It's a "smart pointer" only insofar as the documentation describes it as such. Not a precise definition at all, but since it presents the example I've shown above immediately after saying only smart pointers should implement Deref, presumably the Rust documentation considers that a smart pointer.  The reason I'm trying to do this with an enum, then, is because I want to use the smart pointer presented in the documentation, but with a limited range. The enum seems like a reasonable evolution.

Comment: `X` *may* be a smart pointer (depending on its intentions) that *points* to a `u8` *value*. Something can't be a "smart pointer" without something to "point" to. The discriminant of an enum `Y` doesn't seem to fit that pattern, its more a property of itself. However, the most important question is the one you haven't answered: *What do you hope to achieve with this?* That will help us understand your use-case and steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @kmdreko It really is conceptually what I said. I'm wrapping an integer to give it meaningful semantics (e.g. position of a button on a PCB). It is bounded (e.g. I only have 5 buttons), and I want the compiler to enforce this at the type-level. I  want to do math on it, need its num value. Whether this is semantically a "smart pointer" is not important the way I see it, because the only  difference between my two examples is that one is  bounded 0-255, and the other 0-5. Hence, my question. Perhaps if Rust had bounded integers like Ada, I wouldn't have gone down this route.

Comment: That all sounds sensible, but why do you need `Deref` to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum Y {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H,
}
union Z {
    // Invariant:
    // a) Following field is always valid.
    pub enumer: Y,
    integer: u8,
}
impl std::ops::Deref for Z {
    type Target = u8;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe {
            // Safety: all representations of `u8` are valid.
            // Additionally they are counterparts 
            //  of respective `#[repr(u8)]` `enum` they encode. 
            &self.integer
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let z = Z { enumer: Y::B };
    assert_eq!(dbg!(*z + 2), 3);
}
```

Alternative hack you can use if you don't want to mess with unsafe:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Y {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H,
}

impl std::ops::Deref for Y {
    type Target = u8;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        [&0, &1, &2, &3, &4, &5, &6, &7][*self as usize]
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(dbg!(1 + *Y::B), 2);
}
```

As far as I know, what you are asking for is an unexposed aspect of `enum` memory representation.

So you probably won't get that reference in the normal way.